# Upgrading PHP 5.3 to 7.x on CentOS 6.10 (final) - Unmet Dependencies

Tags: linux, centos, php, centos6, php7

I am a bit rusty these days and could use some help. I've cracked opened a few old servers and have started the process of dusting them off. In the process I'm updating things like PHP. I regret to inform you I'm running 5.3.3. I would like to upgrade it to 7.3.

```
cat /etc/centos-release 
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
```

My PHP version

```
php -v
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Mar 22 2017 12:17:33)
```

Alas, I'm having issues...

I am using the remi repo

```
yum install http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
```

And set my config manager as follows:

```
yum-config-manager --enable remi-php72
```

When I install PHP

```
yum install php php-mcrypt php-cli php-gd php-curl php-mysql php-ldap php-zip php-fileinfo
```

I get a series of dependency errors:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-7.2.10-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
           Requires: libgssapi_krb5.so.2()(64bit)
Error: Package: php-7.2.10-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
           Requires: libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit)
Error: Package: php-cli-7.2.10-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (remi-php72)
           Requires: libcrypt.so.1()(64bit)
And the list goes on....
```

I'm at a loss for how to go about addressing this and could use any help / insights you might have to offer.

Thank you in advance!

Pedro

Comment: Everything is in the base/updates repository

Comment: Perhaps if you tried to update/upgrade iso. install?

Comment: @RemiCollet from the horse's mouth?

Answer (score 2):

Everything is in the base/updates repository

- libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => **krb5-libs**-1.10.3-65.el6.x86_64
- libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) => **glibc**-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64
- libcrypt.so.1()(64bit) => **glibc**-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64

As some package are always there (e.g. glibc)
Check you are really running CentOS 6.10

```
# cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
# uname -a
Linux foo.bar 2.6.32-754.2.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jul 13 12:50:12 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# rpm -q glibc
glibc-2.12-1.212.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @remicollet  <br/>

Here is my configuration:  <br/>

`# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
# uname -a
Linux server.com 4.15.13-x86_64-linode106 #1 SMP Tue Mar 27 14:42:14 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# rpm -q glibc
glibc-2.12-1.212.el6.i686`

Comment: duplicate of https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=67921  (with answer about mixing 32-bit and 64-bit configuration)

Comment: Check that someone has not modified or disabled those base and updates repos.

Answer (score -1):

You could also consider the option of using "ius" repository (https://ius.io/Philosophy/#overview) , which maintains compatibility with stock packages, and let you install php 7 besides the "official" php 5.x. IUS repository uses therefore alternate package naming (https://ius.io/Packages/ => php71u-*.ius.el6.

Comment: Out of topic, issue is with base repo. More: this is wrong, IUS does NOT allow to "install php 7 besides the "official" php " (only SCLs allow parallel installation)

Comment: It seems like IUS repository for CentOS 6 only goes up to PHP 7.1 https://repo.ius.io/6/x86_64/packages/p/